# jQuery .click() .animate() not working

Tags: jquery, click, jquery-animate

The events called inside of $('.transparent-close').click(function(){ ...}); don't seem to be working. Is it possibly because it is inside of another .click() event?

```
$('#featured-top').click(function(){
    $(this).animate({'top':'-318px'}, 600, 'easeOutBounce');
    $('#featured-top-container').animate({'margin':'260px 0 0 117px'}, 600, 'easeOutBounce');
    $('#wrap').animate({'margin-top':'365px'}, 600, 'easeOutBounce');

    //Add transparent background for click out
    $(document.body).append('<div class="transparent-close"></div>');
    $('.transparent-close').click(function(){
        $('#featured-top').animate({'top':'-318px'}, 600, 'easeOutBounce');
        $('#featured-top-container').animate({'margin':'260px 0 0 117px'}, 600, 'easeOutBounce');
        $('#wrap').animate({'margin-top':'365px'}, 600, 'easeOutBounce');
        $(this).remove();
    });
});
```

Comment: Have you ran it through a debugger?

Comment: Yes. No errors, but it doesn't fire the events inside of $('.transparent-close').click(function(){ ...});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use:

```
$('body').append(
    $('<div></div>')
        .addClass('transparent-close')
        .on('click',function(){
            //...
        });
);
```

I had yet problems using click function as an event listener, even if I don't know exactly why.